# Google play store automatically setting max api level for a new apk

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded a new apk to the play store, setting the target and min sdk levels in gradle like this:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 21

    versionCode 6
    versionName '1.5'

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
}
```

But now the pla store developer console reports that this apk is available for api 10-18 and the play store reports:

```
Requires Android
2.3.3 - 4.3
```

AndroidManifest.xml does not contain any reference to api level.

Why is google play automatically setting 18 as the max sdk level?

Comment: U have installed SDK version 21 based on platfrom android? ex. ("C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-21)

Comment: What happens if u are installing it manusally from direct location?

Comment: if you didn't give `maxSdkVersion` play store always pic max api level.

Comment: @Yugesh: Why would you say that? maxSdkVersion is not recommended: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html The target is set to 21, so why would the play store be enforcing 18?